# Does Pinterest need to authorize an App ID prior to OAuth working?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, pinterest

Looking around and especially following the Pinterest API docs, I think I've set everything up correctly, but still get `error NSError: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)"` when I try to log in.  Granted the SDK docs are in Objective-C, but I think my Swift conversion looks ok?  The only thing I can think of is that they have to approve the APP ID on their end maybe?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        PDKClient.configureSharedInstanceWithAppId("XXX")


        return true
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        let pdkClient: PDKClient = PDKClient.sharedInstance()
        return pdkClient.handleCallbackURL(url)
    }



PDKClient.sharedInstance().getAuthenticatedUserPinsWithFields(Set(["id", "image", "note"]), success:
            { (pdk :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in
            print("success /(pdk)")
            }) { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
                print("error NSError: \(err)")
        }

 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>pinterestsdk.v1</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>pinit</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was missing another key in my info.plist, I added the below (that I found in the SDK's example app) and I'm authenticating successfully now:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>pdkXXX</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: Do you have to wait until the app has been approved? Im getting this error (401) but the app is still in development

Comment: no, the app doesn't need to be approved for your call to work...my guess your error either is (1) related to app transport security, see my code above or (2) your API call is incorrectly written.

Comment: I do all the thing it needs, but still get this error. The app on Pinterest still not get approved after 1 week, so i cancel inserting Pinterest button to my App. User can use share sheet. Stupid pinterest

Answer (score -1):

Before making call to the getAuthenticatedUserPinsWithFields method ensure that you have proper permissions.

```
  if(PDKClient.sharedInstance().authorized == false)
    {
       PDKClient.sharedInstance().authenticateWithPermissions([PDKClientReadPrivatePermissions,PDKClientReadPublicPermissions,PDKClientReadRelationshipsPermissions,PDKClientWritePublicPermissions,PDKClientWritePrivatePermissions,PDKClientWriteRelationshipsPermissions], withSuccess: { (response : PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in

           // call getAuthenticatedUserPinsWithFields method here



            }, andFailure: { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
                print(error.description)
        })
    }
```